# Replacement Crank Arm?

Tags: crankset, pedals

Hi I have a 12 spline left crankarm to replace but can't find the right-hand side crankarm.

got ok for 12 spline its just the size.

My one is TR7JAED 165

[image]

Comment: 12 spline power spline

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Truvativ-Left-Crank-Blaze-11-6100-023-070/dp/B001CJZ5R6/ref=cts_sp_2_vtp think its this one but mine old one is longer ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Bicycles.SE! Can you [edit] your question to clarify what your question is? Is it that you don't know what RHS crankarm matches, or you know what matches but are wondering where to get it, or something else?

Comment: It's not the one you've linked to on Amazon, that uses an ISIS interface to the BB. What you need is a Truvativ Powerspline interface, which as you correctly stated has 12 splines. Not sure exactly what the question is but you might find it easier to replace both cranks as it's probably unlikely that you'll find a matching drive-side crank for your existing one given its age. There are still cranksets (and bottom brackets) available which use the Truvativ Powerspline interface so you should be able to find a set of cranks pretty easily.

Comment: I've put your question on hold because, as @shoover indicates, it's unclear what you're asking. If you use the edit button to clarify, your question will automatically be flagged for to be reopened.

Comment: Ah, classic stackexchange... Anyway, it's probably easier to replace bottom bracket and both cranks than search for one crank that fits rare obsolete bottom bracket

Answer (score 1):

All I can tell you is that its a 165mm long crank, and **probably** uses the ISIS interface to the bottom bracket.

Check your BB and see which one is most like your existing BB.  
[image: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/images/bbsx4-labeled.jpg] 
I know of no 12 spline standard off hand, so either its a miscount of the 10 spline ISIS or you've got some weird standard.  Truvativ was known for weird oddball standards too... good luck!

It appears to date from the mid-late 2000s.

The pictured crankarm is a left hand side.  The right hand side crankarm has an integrated Spider to hold the crank arms, and looks something like this:

[image: https://picclick.co.uk/Truvativ-Touro-crank-arms-175mm-vintage-triple-chainset-153625953947.html]  
  Note this one has a square taper drive.  Yours has a different interface, so need to match the BB on your bike.

[image: https://www.picclickimg.com/00/s/MTE0MVgxMzk0/z/9IMAAOSwPVFcVsdI/$/Truvativ-Touro-crank-arms-175mm-vintage-triple-chainset-_57.jpg]  
This one is a triple, because it has boltholes for more than one chainring.  It will be spaced so the middle chainring is in the middle of the cassette.  If you use this with a double chainring, it will sit a little too far out of line.

Other info: There's a wealth of measurements and data at https://www.sheldonbrown.com/bbsize.html  to help you find what you've got and what it is called.